# Move inline form to the right in nav

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the code at https://codepen.io/hby123/project/editor/ANGLnn, how can I move the inline form to the right? I'm using Boostrap 4. I have attempted to use the float-right class, but it's not working. Am I missing something here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <!--  Meta  -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>My Site</title>

  <!--  Styles  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container">

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Site</a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup" style="background-color: lime;">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </div>


        <form class="form-inline">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>

      </div>

    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can give your form a class "form-right" and add the following styles as below.**

```
.form-right{
 width: 100% !important;
 justify-content: flex-end !important;
}
```